# Missing form values when dumping POST using dd in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, post

I have a VERY simple test app based [on Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/11) which is not submitting data via in a very simple view and returns only the CSRF token and no data when submitting.  I'm unclear what step I've missed...

My route is:

```
Route::post('/posts', 'PostsController@store');
```

My form in my View is:

```
  <form method="POST" action="/posts">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="hidden" id="mytest" value="denis">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="title">Title</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="title">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="body">Body</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="body" placeholder="Body"></textarea>
    </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Publish</button>
  </form>
```

My PostsController is:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function store()
    {
      dd(request()->all());
    }
}
```

Posting of my form results in this:

```
array:1 [
    "_token" => "43xJev3Xo2hh88r0IoHRJpoNhn4w3eVztgxbpNAY"
]
```

And NOT something like this (which is the problem):

```
array:1 [
    "_token" => "43xJev3Xo2hh88r0IoHRJpoNhn4w3eVztgxbpNAY"
    "title" => "My test post title"
    "body" => "My test body value"
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the "name" attribute on your input and textarea.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `name` attributes. It appears you have it mixed up with the `id` attribute (as seen in the hidden input).

```
<form method="POST" action="/posts">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="mytest" value="denis">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="title">Title</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title" placeholder="title">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="body">Body</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" name="body" id="body" placeholder="Body"></textarea>
    </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Publish</button>
</form>
```